# CakePHP: controllers are accessible even though they inherit from AuthenticatedController

Tags: cakephp

I have a CakePHP app that has both a publicly accessible part, and a part that requires authentication. All controllers that require authentication inherit from the following controller:

```
class AuthenticatedController extends AppController {
public $components = array(
        'Cookie',
        'Auth' => array(
                'authenticate' => array(
                        'Form' => array(
                                'fields' => array('username' => 'email_address')
                                )
                        ),
                'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'),
                'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'index')
        )
);

// authentication issues
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!$this->Auth->login()) {        
            // redirect
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Articles', 'action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
        }
    }
}

public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
}
```

For some reason, some controllers, when I try to access them via the web, will redirect to Users/login as required. Others will not - they are completely accessible even though they inherit from AuthenticatedController.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Maybe it's not related with your problem but I don't see why you are  putting `login` and `logout` function in your `AuthenticatedController`. They should be located in `UsersController`. With your code you have a `login` action for every Model. i.e. `Posts/login`, `Comments/login` and so on

Comment: That's the point - I need to enforce login for all controllers that inherit from this one.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you had an application where all controllers needed authentication you still would put login just in UsersController. I don't think you'll never call a posts/login action (supposing you have a Post model).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create two different kinds of controller

just create authentication for all your application (so configuring it in your AppController)

then in every controller who need public access put

```
$this->Auth->allow('*');
```

or

```
$this->Auth->allow();
```

in the `beforeFilter` function

it depends on your cake version (always remember to specify your exact version)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to do the opposite: I'm trying to make this behave the way that it should, which means to NOT allow anything in my controllers, once auth has been configured in AppController.
But your answer did bring me closer: I tried adding this line of code to beforeFilter in 2 controllers, one which behaves as it should (not allowing access without auth), and the other which does not behave as it should. In the one that doesn't behave well, I get the following error:

     Error: Call to a member function allow() on a non-object

Why would Auth not be an object for any controller?

Comment: let **all** the controllers use Auth component and then use Auth to make public actions. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#making-actions-public